# Calculate Stages in Non-Pipelined Processor

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-pipelines

I have tried to attempt a question where I have to find the number of stages for non-pipelined processor(8085) for below program :-

```
MOV #40, R00
MOV #50, R01
MOV #60, R02
SUB R02, R01 
ADD R02, R01 
INC R01
SUB R00, R02 
HLT
```

What will be the no. of stages and there list here?

Comment: Think about it: How are we supposed to know? It depends on the processor. You know which processor it is, we don't.

Comment: @gnasher729  It is 8085 processor.

Answer (score 0):

That processor should come with a manual. If yes, you can use the information in the manual. If no, you can google for the manual, like "8085 manual". The number of cycles and states for each instruction are in chapter 3, for example CPI = 7 states. Then you add up the numbers.

Comment: I am Sorry, but I am not getting your point. I want to know the number of Stages not states, here clocks=44, Instruction count=8, CPI=5.5 and Speed up Factor=.91. I am new to the subject, so please help me in understanding it.

Comment: Neither stages nor states is a standard term, but "states" _was_ used in the 1980's. "States" is what the 8085 manual uses. It doesn't use the word "Stage" anywhere. It also doesn't use the word "clocks" but "cycles", so your teacher seems to have changed the terminology. PS. CPI = "ComPare Immediate" instruction.

Comment: In this context, CPI = cycles per instruction.